# What is the difference between kosoto-gari and kosoto-gake?

Tags: judo, technique, terminology, throwing

*Kosoto-gari* and *kosoto-gake* are superficially similar techniques. I have seen many high level judoka call what I would have called *-gari* *-gake* and vice versa - what distinguishes these techniques?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Excerpt of Canonical Answer

This quotation is attributed to Kyuzo Mifune on page 162 of *Kodokan Judo: Throwing Techniques* by Toshiro Daigo.

> Sweeping is similar to brushing an extremely light object away.
>
> When hooking, you execute the technique as if pulling a rooted plant out from the ground.
>
> Reaping is similar to the movement of reaping and cutting off a plant at its root with a sickle.

A *kosoto gari* is reap, where the side of *tori's* foot maintains contact with the mat. A *kosoto gake* is a hooking, where *tori's* leg bends and *tori's* foot comes off the mat.

As a strict classification issue, the key point is the action of *tori's* attacking leg. Does it leave the mat? Then it's a *gake*. Otherwise it's a *gari*.

### Personal thoughts

I find *kosoto gake* to be most effective as a counter technique. The opponent enters for a throw where they are turning their back and standing on one leg (for example: *harai goshi*, *hane goshi*, *uchi mata*, *ashi guruma*), and you disrupt their balance and attack the far leg. As a strict Kodokan classification, this throwing action may unfortunately be classified as a *harai goshi gaeshi*, *hane goshi gaeshi*, or *uchi mata gaeshi*. Note that this does not apply to all throws, only these three. A counter to *ashi guruma* is not an *ashi guruma gaeshi* because this is not recognized as a distinct throw.

At the close distance for the counter and *uke's* weight firmly on the supporting foot, I find timing of *kuzushi* with the body and a strong hooking action necessary to successfully counter. For *kosoto gari*, the action of the hands becomes more important to break *uke's* balance over the heels to setup the reap.